# В каком типе питона хранить настройки программы?

Tags: python, settings, настройки

Хочется получить и хранить настройки изолировано и обращаться из переменной.
Т.е. типа

```
def settings() 
 a = list()
 ...
 return a
```

Не нравится что потом приходится обращаться к значениям не красиво через точку

```
m = a.key1
```

а так

```
m =  a['key1']
```

А нельзя хранить настройке в объекте класса? Смущает только что нужно создавать целый класс для одного объекта. Или это нормально так?

В целом верные ли у меня рассуждения?

Comment: Если у вас Python 3.7 и выше, можно датаклассы использовать, их намного проще описывать. Или модели pydantic (которые внутри те же датаклассы). Нет ничего плохого в том, чтобы использовать целый класс для одного объекта.

Answer (score 3):

> А нельзя хранить настройке в объекте класса?

Можно. Например с помощью [Data classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-dataclasses):

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Settings:
    a: str = 'Spam!'
    b: str = 'Eggs'


settings = Settings()

settings.a  # Spam!
settings.b  # Eggs
```

---

Ещё есть вариант хранить настройки программы в отдельном модуле. Создайте файл `settings.py` и добавьте в него необходимые константы, затем просто импортируйте его:

```py
import settings

settings.a  # Spam!
settings.b  # Eggs
```

Comment: Наверное еще и заглавными буквами стоит обозвать константы в сеттингзах?)

Comment: @AndyPavlov Да, я бы использовал заглавные. Но принципиальной разницы нет. Автор использует строчные, поэтому в ответе привожу строчные.

Comment: а зачем заглавные?

Comment: @vi0 Использование заглавных букв для констант — это неформальное соглашение между программистами. Так легче отличить переменные, которые изменяются по ходу действия программы от тех, которые не изменяются

Comment: @vi0 полистайте pep8 раздел Naming Conventions https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions